# Read file into Buffer Chunks of 32 bytes

Tags: java, swing, io, bufferedreader, jfilechooser

I have a requirement to do the following after opening a txt file using JFileChooser

- Buffer chunks of 32 bytes; each row saves id (in column 1, succession number starting from 1) and the 32 bytes. The buffer size of the last row may be less than 32 byes, in which case pad it with ‘*’.
- Display the content of the buffer.

Could anyone guide on the understanding of the requirement?. I have implemented the code t read the characters from file but not sure if i'm close to the requirements.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(JFileChooserDemo.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            char[] buf = new char[32];
            int numRead = 0;
            int index = 1;
            try {
                while ((numRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    System.out.println(numRead);
                    String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
                    if (numRead == 32) {
                        fileData.append(" " + index + " " + readData);
                        index++;
                    } else {
                        fileData.append(" * " + readData);
                        index = 0;
                    }
                    buf = new char[32];
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(fileData);
        }
    }

    //Handle save button action.
}
```

Comment: *"Could anyone guide on how to read file data into buffer chunks of 32bytes?"*  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help.  And please do not mistake that 'uncompilable code snippet' for an attempt, at best it is a template that implies, 'please insert answer here'.

Comment: Since it is a text file I assume you want to read 32 characters and not bytes. Otherwise it would be difficult if you just have a `Reader` to work with.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have tried and updated the code. Still not sure if that is what expected from requirements. Do I need to create a custom type to store id and 32 bytes per each read?.

Comment: @Henry Updated the code. Could you have a relook at it?.